# Android - other app stealing my intent receiver?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an app which uses the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent with a BroadcastReceiver to control a music player. The user pushes a button on external hardware and it controls the in-app music player. The user can also HOLD DOWN the button and change the volume.

I recently downloaded another app which uses the headset button, and it takes over the media button intent from my app! So when this other app is open and I press the button, the other app will start running, but my app will think that the button is still pressed down so it will cycle the volume.

To summarize,

- my app is open, supposed to be sole listener of media button intents
- other app gets opened, it also wants to be sole listener of media button intents
- button gets pressed with both apps open, control goes to other app
- my app thinks the button is being held down, as it lost control as the button was pressed in down mode (I think). It then launches functions I don't want launched because it thinks the user has held down the button.

Is there any way I could make sure that while my app is open it's the sole receiver of this media button intent? Could I at least check to see if another app has taken over, so I can prevent unexpected behaviour?

Thank you for any help, I've never had apps not play nicely before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your BroadcastReceiver's priority (make it something large, like 10000): it should then get the Intent first, and then you can pass it on to the other app.

Comment: ... until another custom app gets installed which has priority for the same broadcast 20000 :)

Comment: Well, it is an arms race, true :). The dark side of the intent exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar issue. I believe, outside of the 'arms race' over the priorites mentioned, the only real solution is to close the other application. If you are releasing this application to other users, you could possibly give them a message telling them to close other media player apps and services.

In your manifest you can set the intent priority to the max value of an integer which is: 2147483647.

You should not however set your IntentFilter priority over 1000 as it tells you in the API docs. You can set the IntentFilter priority like so:

```
myIntentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
```

I assume you should subtract one from the SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY constant as the docs say the value must be less than SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY.

Quote from docs about IntentFilter.setPriority(int):

> Applications must use a value that is larger than SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY and smaller than SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY.